# Error: El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres IFormCollection no se encontró

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mvc

Recién estoy empezando con .NET y me sale siguiente error:

> El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres `IFormCollection` no se
> encontró

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, IFormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y te fijaste en la documentacion que tenias que importar? y el error no es en .net, sera en c#?

Comment: `IFormCollection` es parte del namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`. Asegurate de que exista en las referencias del proyecto

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error significa que estas intentando utilizar una parte de `.net` de la cual no tienes referencia.

Por ejemplo: Para utilizar `Console.WriteLine`, `Console` es una clase que existe dentro del namespace `System`, entonces tendrias que tener `Using System;` al inicio de tu programa para poder utilizar la clase `Console`.

Puedes hecharle un vistaso a este video:
[Introduccion a c#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSMybHaYddo&ab_channel=KudvenkatSpanish) en el cual doy una breve introduccion a C# y explico lo del using  y namespaces.

Ahora para poder resolver tu problema podrias hacer esto (si estas trabajando con visual studio):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo pones le mouse encima del error, entonces te aparece un icono vas hasta la flecha en el icono y te va mostrar una lista de posibles soluciones, entre las soluciones la ultima es buscar la clase en algun namespace o nuget dentro del framework de .net, alli mismo ira a buscarlo online y lo instalara, tambien agregara la referencias necesarias.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.